# Can I Set Up Routes That Include The Locale & Default the Locale In The Route When It Is Not Provided?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing, i18n-gem

I currently have routing that requires the locale (i.e. /en, /fr, etc.).  At some point I have used all of the statements below in routes.rb:

```
scope "/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do

scope "/:locale", defaults: { :locale => "en" } do

scope "/:locale" do
```

I know that if I do the following if the route does not include the locale that it will point to the English version of the website.  However it does not set the locale like I want once the page is displayed.  If I go to the French version by clicking my locale logic the first link will display the French version of the page with /fr in the link.  However if I click another link on the French page the locale goes back to English with the locale excluded from the link.

```
scope "(/:locale)", defaults: { :locale => "en" } do
```

Here is the code for my locale links in my application where a user can click on a flag image or text to change the locale:

```
<%= link_to_unless_current image_tag("english.jpg", alt: "#{t :english}"), locale: "en" %> <%= link_to_unless_current "#{t :english}", locale: "en" %>
<%= link_to_unless_current image_tag("french.jpg", alt: "#{t :french}"), locale: "fr" %> <%= link_to_unless_current "#{t :french}", locale: "fr" %>
```

What I would like to do is to prevent a 500 system error if by chance someone has an link saved before the website was localized.  For example if they have http://mywebsite.com/video it would display the English version of the website and set the locale to "en".

Here is the code I have in application_controller.rb.

```
  before_filter :set_locale

  def default_url_options(options={}) 
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end

  private
    def set_locale
      I18n.locale = (params[:locale] if params[:locale].present?) || cookies[:locale] || 'en'
      cookies[:locale] = I18n.locale if cookies[:locale] != I18n.locale.to_s
    end
```

I'm not finding anything on this particular issue other than to use the routing-filter gem.  I was using the gem but until there is a production version of the gem for Rails 4 I have no option but to figure this routing issue out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried manually setting the locale in the ApplicationController by using a before_filter? I remember having similar issues about locals getting forgot in the views and resorted to it.

Comment: I have updated my question with what I have in ApplicationController.  It still does not set the locale in the URL if it is missing.  I have another question posted about custom error pages not working because of a missing locale.  It sets the locale to the error number.  I want to set the routing and not determine it by the person's computer.  Maybe a minor change in ApplicationController will fix both of my problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i find your question rather confusing... so my answer will refer to some parts of you code. maybe that gives you enough context to fix your problems.

1. do not use 3 routes for locale

one route is enough, please read [the guides for internationlization](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setup-the-rails-application-for-internationalization).

i think that you will have to go with the optional approach as you want to support legacy urls:

`scope "(/:locale)" {}`

1. use the `config.default_locale` option

in the configuration you can configure fallbacks for localization.

1. don't mix `default_url_options` and `cookies`

if you are using cookies to keep track of your locale, you can can skip the `default_url_options`, you will have to keep the unlocalized versions anyways for backward compatibility.

if you MUST have urls like `domain.com/en/something` do it the other way around. avoid using cookies, use the URL everywhere and redirect people coming in from a legacy url.

Comment: I get a 500 server error without default_url_options. This is why I added it as the i18n guide says. The default for config.i18n.default_locale is English.  Is this the same as config.default_locale?. How can a selected locale be saved on a computer without using a cookie? I don't want the user to have to select the locale every time. I have many bilingual users. I want the locale included in the URL which is what I have coded. How do I redirect legacy URLs and where do I put the code? Do I need to redirect each route individually or can I check if the locale is missing in a route generically?

Comment: I have read the guide to redirect individual routes from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection. However I'm not sure how to do this within a scope statement since I want to include the locale in the URL. The examples in the guide are similar to what I have coded. I do not see how I could check if the locale is missing in the route. Maybe there is a generic way to check this outside of the routes file. Thanks so much for your input.

Comment: I was working on other features and decided to implement your suggestion.  I had tried this before but was getting unexpected results.  My guess is that I had other errors.  It is working like I want.  When people click the links on the website it will show the locale like I want.  However if someone wants to go to the link and forgets the locale it will go to the English version.  I did not set the default_locale since the default for Rails is English.  Thanks so much!